# I want to find out the highest value in in cells, themselves in ranges of cells

Tags: filter, google-sheets, ranking, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

My background is not in programming so I hope someone can help me with this problem, maybe there's a simple answer, I can do it manually, but I can't automate it.

This is a simplification, but I have bird sightings by region, by a person, in a sheet. I want to automate it so that each person's sightings in a region is given an order number, highest to lowest. i.e. the person with most sightings is given "1", the second highest "2", and so on.

At the moment I do the ordering by eye, but I make mistakes, and it's time-consuming

Example data (this data is in a sheet):

```
Region          Person     Sightings    Order_No

Poole           John       12            ?_(2)
Poole           John_A     14            ?_(1)
Poole           Chris      10            ?_(3)
Wareham         John        5            ?_(3)
Wareham         John_A     19            ?_(2)
Wareham         Chris      21            ?_(1)
```

The values I want Google Sheets to calculate automatically are the values I've put in brackets. These are the values I input myself manually at the moment

The sheet is constantly being updated, with new rows being added, and existing being edited (so I might add a new row for a new person in Poole, or change the sightings for Poole/John from 12 to another value). If possible I want the order number to change, as I make changes to the data.

I've tried using Query, and VLookup, and Array formula, but unfortunately it's really hard for me to even get them to work at all. If someone can show me how to approach the problem, or solve it and show me the syntax, then that'll really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **D2** cell and drag down:

```
=RANK(C2, FILTER(C:C, A:A=A2), 0)
```

[image: 0]

### _______________________________________________________

one-cell solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SORT(ROW(A2:A), SORT(ROW(A2:A), A2:A, 0, C2:C, 0), 1)-
 MATCH(A2:A, SORT(A2:A, 1, 0), 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Just tried the first answer and it works perfectly. Will now try and understand what's going on with the code for future reference. Brilliant!